# List of Visual Studio 2010 setup project text variables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I'm looking for a list of variables that I can use in text fields in the Visual Studio 2010 setup project.

For example the Welcome dialog box has this text by default:

> The installer will guide you through the steps required to install
>   [ProductName] on your computer.

I'm looking to other variables like [ProductName], so I can do something like:

> The installer will guide you through the steps required to install
>   [ProductName] v[Version] on your computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Press F4 after you select your setup project in the solution explorer. You can see list of variables there, like [ProductName], [Manufacturer], [Description], [Author] and [Version], etc.

The whole property list can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905.aspx

Comment: I've already tried using the property names of the setup project, but only [ProductName] and [Manufacturer] work. I found that [ProductVersion] also works, but would really like the whole list.

Comment: Edited my answer.Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: `TargetPlatform` shows in the properties window, but not listed in the page you have shared. I was just trying to add a condition to exclude a file if target machine were not 64-bit.