# .NET Application version display

Tags: c#, .net, version, teamcity, installation

I'm using TeamCity as a CI tool.

In "Build Step" section I added an AssemblyInfo patcher build feature which updates assemblies version during build. A setup project builds for me an install for my application. After application install - assemblies have correct version.

But when I go to "Programs and Features" - for my application is displayed a totally different version value.

Could You tell me how to manage the version displayed in "Programs and Features"?

Comment: That version is set by installer tool. Are you using WIX, InstallShield or something like that?

Comment: I'm using the standard setup project from Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your Visual Studio setup project. Press F4 to get the properties (not exactly sure its F4, @AccessDenied says it's TAB). Locate the `Version` property in there.

See couple of other relevant answers for some additional info:

- [List of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8639195/706456)
- [Uninstalling previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332235/706456)
- [Screenshot of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640475/visual-studio-set-up-doesnt-uninstall-previous-version-of-the-build)

Answer (score 1):

Version displayed in `Programs and Features` is not the `exe` version. It is the `setup version`.

To change that you've t modify the setup version.

Answer (score 1):

Programs and Features displays the Installer version. To change the version

1. Select the Installer project
2. Select Properties tab (*Don't right click and go to property*)
3. You will find the Version property at the end with the default version is `1.0.0`